# Changing color in geom_node_point() from ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, ggraph

I have a long dataframe with the following structure:

| FROM | TO | WEIGHT | NAME_1 | NAME_2 | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.1 | name_1 | name_2 | category_a |
| 2 | 3 | 0.3 | name_2 | name_3 | category_b |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 195 | 33 | 0.2 | name_195 | name_33 | category_a |

The idea is to plot the network. For this, the following code works:

```
library(ggraph)
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
ggraph(graph, layout = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(alpha = range01(weight), width = range01(weight)), edge_colour = "grey") +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.1, 3))+
  geom_node_point(aes(color = "red", size = 5)) +
  ggtitle("Text Network") +
  labs(tag = "Figure 2") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.position = "none", plot.title=element_text( hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, face='bold'))
```

However, when I try to color the nodes based on their category (I have 7 different categories), I get an error:

```
library(ggraph)
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
ggraph(graph, layout = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(alpha = range01(weight), width = range01(weight)), edge_colour = "grey") +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.1, 3))+
  geom_node_point(aes(color = graph$category, size = 5)) +
  ggtitle("Text Network") +
  labs(tag = "Figure 2") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.position = "none", plot.title=element_text( hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5, face='bold'))
```

In particular, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (195): colour
```

I already tried many of the solutions provided in other questions (for example, adding "factor(graph$category)" or using just "category"). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was that instead of using

```
geom_node_point(aes(color = graph$category, size = 5))
```

It has to be

```
geom_node_point(aes(color = V(graph2)$category, size = 5))
```